# Rocker bogie suspension system - pitch angle

Tags: mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, rocker-bogie

What does this sentence mean :

"The chassis maintains the average pitch angle of both rockers."

Put in other words, " the pitching angle of the chassis is the average of the pitch angles of the two rocker arms"

What is a pitching angle in this context? 
Please explain both pitching angles.

Answer (score 2):

The "pitch angle" or "pitching angle" refers to whether the chassis is level.  An angle of 0 degrees would be perfectly flat, 90 degrees would be perfectly vertical.  So if the vehicle's left side went up a 30 degree incline while the right side stayed flat, the chassis should tilt up 15 degrees.

To achieve this, the two sides of the rocker-bogie suspension are connected by a simple differential.

[image: rocker bogie suspension]
<sub>(source: [alicesastroinfo.com](http://www.alicesastroinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/MSL-c-anim-200.gif))</sub>

[image: detail]
<sub>(source: [alicesastroinfo.com](http://www.alicesastroinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/MER-txt-640.jpg))</sub>

See also [this answer which includes an image of the differential bar on the curiosity rover](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/1241/350).

Comment: One can clearly see that this is not on mars from the angles of the shadows. Totally fake. ;-)